# cakePHP : how ACL allow action in plugin?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I have plugin

```
  plugin: tree 
  -----controller: tree
  -------------action : admin_index
```

DB Table aros_acos has updated _CRUD 1 1 1 1 for this aco.
I code $this->Acl->check(array('model'=>'User','foreign_key'=>2),'Tree/Tree/admin_index');

error:

```
DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [model] => User
    [foreign_key] => 2
)

Aco: Tree/Tree/admin_index [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 273]
```

All other action  is permission valid but action of plugins, I cant find reason . Anyone help me.

Comment: What is your console output for `cake acl view aco`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have Tree as a plugin - it's a core behaviour.

Please post the *appropriate* rows from the aros_acos table.

The array you pass into `Acl->check` doesn't look right to me. I pass in the output of $this->Auth->user() which looks like:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [username] => somebody
            [group_id] => 1
        )
)
```

Have a look at Mark Story's tutorial - it really is excellent:
http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1

Comment: He uses the correct syntax - http://book.cakephp.org/view/1249/Checking-Permissions-The-ACL-Component

Answer (score 0):

1. There was a change in Cakephp 1.3. Only the `index` route is [supported](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1118/Plugin-Tips) for the controller that is named the same as plugin. So, you will need to handle that first if you use 1.3 version.
2. Check the ARO and ACO tree in the console: `cake acl view aco`, `cake acl view aro`. Try to check the permissions from console `cake acl check YOURARO YOURACO all`